Can't embed YouTube video
Just pasting the embed code inside an HTML Block, and getting a "cannot embed" error:
Paste a link to the content you want to display on your site: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5R_SxV-cFY
It gives the error

"Sorry, this content could not be embedded"

See image of error screen:

I'm trying this by using Embed Block, Youtube Block, and so on but didn't find any solution, even I asked this question to chatGPT and found said plugin issue and I deactivated all plugins but nothing fix.
Any solution or fix for this?

An alternative could be:
Use a Custom HTML block and embed the video with this HTML code:
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/h5R_SxV-cFY">IFRAME is not supported in your browser</iframe>


Instead "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5R_SxV-cFY" try using "https://www.youtube.com/embed/h5R_SxV-cFY"

I also tried the same, but nothing works.
